# Could not find or load main class BasicApp.Application

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot and was trying to create a very basic application on spring boot. But, I am getting this error while creating my application.

> Could not find or load main class BasicApp.Application

My Application is having two classes one `Controller` Class and one `Main` Class. Here is my code:

**Application.java**

```
package BasicApp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

public class Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**MainController.java**

```
package BasicApp;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MainController 
{
    @RequestMapping("/send")
    @ResponseBody
    public String sendMessage()
    {
        return("M sending message");
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>SpringBootSecond</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringBootSecond</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>    
    <!-- Spring version -->
    <spring-framework.version>4.1.0.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>    
    <!-- ActiveMQ version -->
    <activemq.version>5.10.0</activemq.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring aritifacts -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>  

    <!-- ActiveMQ Artifacts -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${activemq.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies> 

<!-- Using JDK 1.7 for compiling -->
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<!--    <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </parent>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>spring-releases</id>
                <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>spring-releases</id>
                <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories> -->
</project>
```

Could somebody please help me with this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put @SpringBootApplication annotation to your Application class and it will do all the configuration for you.

Answer (score 0):

see build errors, usually files is zero size , delete bad files in maven folder